# Python: split list into chunks of defined size and fill up rest

Tags: python

I want to split my list into rows that have all the same number of columns, I'm looking for the best (most elegant/pythonic) way to achieve this:

```
>>> split.split_size([1,2,3], 5, 0)
[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]]

>>> split.split_size([1,2,3,4,5], 5, 0)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

>>> split.split_size([1,2,3,4,5,6], 5, 0)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> split.split_size([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 5, 0)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 0, 0, 0]]
```

That's what I came up with so far:

```
def split_size(l, size, fillup):
    """
    splits list into chunks of defined size, fills up last chunk with fillup if below size
    """
    # len(l) % size or size
    # does i.e. size=5: 3->2, 4->1, 5->0
    stack = l + [fillup] * (size - (len(l) % size or size))
    result = []
    while len(stack) > 0:
        result.append(stack[:5])
        del stack[:5]
    return result
```

I'm sure there must be some smarter solutions. Especially for the "inverse mod" part:
    len(l) % size or size
there *must* be a more readable way to do this, no?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Comment: @Volting: I saw this other question, it's related but not the same because but I want to specify the size of each split.

Comment: @NullUserException: indeed the answer is the same, but the question isn't :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) called grouper does what you want:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: [`izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is new in version 2.6

Comment: wow, looking at the izip_longest documentation I could never have come up with this, thanks a lot